# Filtering divs with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, filter

I´m trying to get this function where divs are being filtered out depending on which categories you pick, by using a scriopt i found on codepen. I have never used jquery before so I dont understand whats wrong, but when I try my script on codepen it works.
But when i run it in my browser by opening the html file, it doesn´t work! Sorry if this is a noob question but I don´t understand why it doesn´t work!
If somebody can help me understand what im doing wrong i would be very thankful!

Code from codepen:

Html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sort.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css"/>

    </head>
<body>
    <div>

                        <button class="active btn" data-filter="box">Show All</button>
                        <button class="btn" data-filter="a">Show A</button>
                        <button class="btn" data-filter="b">Show B</button>
                        <button class="btn" data-filter="c">Show C</button>
                        <button class="btn" data-filter="d">Show D</button>

                        <div class="spacer"></div>

                        <div id="parent">
                          <div class="box a b">A &amp; B</div>
                          <div class="box a">A</div>
                          <div class="box b">B</div>
                          <div class="box c a">C &amp; A</div>
                          <div class="box c">C</div>
                          <div class="box d">D</div>
                        </div>
                <br class="clear" />

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
    * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
}
.btn {
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.box {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
}
.spacer {
  clear: both;
  height: 20px;
}
```

js:

```
var $boxs = $("#parent > .box");
var $btns = $(".btn").on("click", function() {

  var active = 
    $btns.removeClass("active")
      .filter(this)
      .addClass("active")
      .data("filter");

  $boxs
    .hide()
    .filter( "." + active )
    .fadeIn(450);

});
```

Comment: Move `<script type="text/javascript" src="sort.js"></script>` before `</body>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your script once the DOM is loaded (*since you include your file in the `head`*)

```
$(function(){
    var $boxs = $("#parent > .box");
    var $btns = $(".btn").on("click", function() {

      var active = 
        $btns.removeClass("active")
          .filter(this)
          .addClass("active")
          .data("filter");

      $boxs
        .hide()
        .filter( "." + active )
        .fadeIn(450);
    });
});
```

---

You also do not need to include the ***jQuery-UI*** (`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>`) for this code..

Comment: OH MY GOD you are my new HERO! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine. Online code editors usually wrap the code in a `load` event handler (*like the stack snippet in this answer*) to make sure it runs after elements are created.

Try wrapping your code inside [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $boxs = $("#parent > .box");
  var $btns = $(".btn").on("click", function() {

    var active =
      $btns.removeClass("active")
      .filter(this)
      .addClass("active")
      .data("filter");

    $boxs
      .hide()
      .filter("." + active)
      .fadeIn(450);

  });

});
```

```js
var $boxs = $("#parent > .box");
var $btns = $(".btn").on("click", function() {

  var active =
    $btns.removeClass("active")
    .filter(this)
    .addClass("active")
    .data("filter");

  $boxs
    .hide()
    .filter("." + active)
    .fadeIn(450);

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
}
.btn {
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px;
}
.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.box {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
}
.spacer {
  clear: both;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div>

  <button class="active btn" data-filter="box">Show All</button>
  <button class="btn" data-filter="a">Show A</button>
  <button class="btn" data-filter="b">Show B</button>
  <button class="btn" data-filter="c">Show C</button>
  <button class="btn" data-filter="d">Show D</button>

  <div class="spacer"></div>

  <div id="parent">
    <div class="box a b">A &amp; B</div>
    <div class="box a">A</div>
    <div class="box b">B</div>
    <div class="box c a">C &amp; A</div>
    <div class="box c">C</div>
    <div class="box d">D</div>
  </div>
  <br class="clear" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using older version of jQuery. User jQuery 2.x and add the below line after your body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sort.js"></script>
```